# How to make imports / closures work from IPython's embed?

Tags: python, import, closures, ipython

I sometimes use `embed` at a certain point in a script to quickly flesh out some local functionality. Minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# ...

import IPython
IPython.embed()
```

Developing a local function often requires a new import. However, importing a module in the IPython session does not seem to work, when used in a function. For instance:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: def local_func(): return os.path.sep

In [3]: local_func()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f0e5d4635432> in <module>()
----> 1 local_func()

<ipython-input-2-c530ce486a2b> in local_func()
----> 1 def local_func(): return os.path.sep

NameError: global name 'os' is not defined
```

This is rather confusing, especially since I can even use tab completion to write `os.path.sep`.

I noticed that the problem is even more fundamental: In general, functions created in the IPython embed session do not close over variables from the embed scope. For instance, this fails as well:

```
In [4]: x = 0

In [5]: def local_func(): return x

In [6]: local_func()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-f0e5d4635432> in <module>()
----> 1 local_func()

<ipython-input-5-2116e9532e5c> in local_func()
----> 1 def local_func(): return x

NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Module names are probably just the most common thing to "close over"...

Is there any solution to this problem?

**Update**: The problem not only applies for closures, but also [nested list comprehensions](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10695).

*Disclaimer: I'll post an (unsatisfactory) answer to the question myself -- still hoping for a better solution though.*

Comment: As of February 2017 I still observe the issue with sys.version being `2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the same problem. I used this trick to deal with the case when the `embed()` is called outside a function, so that `globals()` and `locals()` should be the same dictionary.

The simplest way is to call the following function after ipython is launched

```
ipy = get_ipython()
setattr(ipy.__class__, 'user_global_ns', property(lambda self: self.user_ns))
```

Another way is to subclass `InteractiveShellEmbed`

```
class InteractiveShellEmbedEnhanced(InteractiveShellEmbed):
    @property
    def user_global_ns(self):
        if getattr(self, 'embedded_outside_func', False):
            return self.user_ns
        else:
            return self.user_module.__dict__

    def init_frame(self, frame):
        if frame.f_code.co_name == '<module>':
            self.embedded_outside_func = True
        else:
            self.embedded_outside_func = False
```

and modify slightly the code of `IPython.terminal.embed.embed()` so that in it all `InteractiveShellEmbed` is changed to `InteractiveShellEmbedEnhanced` and call `shell.init_frame(frame)` after the line `shell = InteractiveShellEmbed.instance(...)`.

This is based on the following observations:

- In an ipython session, we always have `id(globals()) == id(ipy.user_module.__dict__) == id(ipy.user_global_ns)` (`user_global_ns` is a class property of the super class of `InteractiveShellEmbed`, which returns `ipy.user_module.__dict__`)
- Also we have `id(locals()) == id(ipy.user_ns)`
- For normal ipython session, `id(locals()) == id(globals())`
- `user_global_ns` (a property) and `user_ns` (a dict) define the execution context
- In embedded ipython, `ipy.user_module` and `ipy.user_ns` are set in function `ipy.__call__()` and passed to `ipy.mainloop()`. They are not the same object since `ipy.user_ns` is constructed inside the functions.

If you are to launch ipython outside a function (like in a script), then it is safe to assume the `globals()` should be identical to `locals()`.

With this setup, the following code should work while not working using the default embedded shell:

```
a=3
(lambda :a)()    # default behavior: name 'a' is not defined
import time
(lambda: time.time())()  # default behavior: name 'time' is not defined
```

(default behavior is due to `a` and `time` are not added to `globals()` and `ipython` does not make closures for local functions (the lambdas defined above) and insists to look up the variables in global scope. search `closure`  [in this page](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/62))

Comment: Very interesting. Do you think it makes sense to contribute that to iPython? Maybe this could close issues [#62](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/62) and [#10695](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10695).

Comment: @bluenote10 I am not an expert in either python or IPython. I am not sure whether the code will work at all circumstances when launched outside a function. I can only share my code and let the experts tell whether it serves as a solution or points to the direction to solve it. I have put a more complete snippet to your [#10695](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10695), which also provides helpers when IPython is embedded from a function.

Answer (score 2):

This "bug" of IPython.embed() is still there today. But from the comment of [developer](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/62#issuecomment-5308175), we could instead use:

```py
from IPython import start_ipython
... # some random code
start_ipython(argv=[], user_ns = locals())
```

Or more aggressively, replace the `user_ns = locals()` to `user_ns = locals() | globals()`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: Again only a work-around, but somewhat simpler: `globals().update(locals())`

---

I don't have a general solution, but at least a work-around: After defining a local function, it is possible to add the `locals()` of the session to the `func_globals` of the function just defined, e.g.:

```
In [1]: import os

In [2]: def local_func(): return os.path.sep

In [3]: local_func.func_globals.update(locals())

In [4]: local_func()
Out[4]: '/'
```

However, one should be aware that this is only a "manual closure" and will not work as a regular closure in cases like this:

```
In [1]: x = 1

In [2]: def local_func(): return x

In [3]: local_func.func_globals.update(locals())

In [4]: local_func()
Out[4]: 1

In [5]: x = 42

In [6]: local_func() # true closure would return 42
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: local_func.func_globals.update(locals()) # but need to update again

In [8]: local_func()
Out[8]: 42
```

At least it can solve the notorious `global name '...' is not defined` problem for imports.